# How to use `[tag:tag-name]` for tags of the meta site?

Tags: support, tagging, markdown

We have two tags with identical names on main and meta:

[(main:computer-science)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science)
and 
[(meta:computer-science)](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science)

For main tags one can use `[tag:computer-science]` , i.e. [computer-science](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computer-science), but it's not possible to address meta tags in the same way. Please tell me if I'm wrong.

Comment: A related question on Meta Stack Exchange: [Is there some markup to post tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66965) (Although I think that the relevant fact from there are already summarized in the answers to this question, too.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can address meta tags like `[meta-tag:computer-science]`: [computer-science](/questions/tagged/computer-science)

Comment: +1 thanks...${ }$

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps it is also useful to mention that the syntax `[meta-tag:feature-request]` is included in the [editing help](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tags) on meta. [Editing help](https://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#tags) on main only mentions the syntax `[tag:elephants]`. (At least as of this moment.)